select with soft edge
How can I select part of an object, with soft edges in the selection, to use in geometric nodes.
I would like to select with soft edge to apply the Edge Wear: Mesh Edge Damage geometry node.
leaving a part of the mesh unchanged by the Geometry Node.
following file with the Geometry node tree.
https://www.youtube.com/live/GfJMABU8U0g
thank you very much for your attention

While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
